# AngularJS reload data after PUT request

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, request, put

Should be a fairly easy one here for anyone who knows Angular. I am trying to update the data that is displayed after I make a `PUT` request to update the object. Here is some code:

Post service (services/post.js)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('hackaboxApp')
  .factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/posts/:id', {id : '@id'}, {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    })
});
```

Server side controller function that gets executed when trying to update data (lib/controllers/api.js)

```
exports.editsave = function(req, res, next) {
  var posty = req.body;

  console.log(posty._id.toString() + " this is posty");

  function callback (err, numAffected) {
    console.log(err + " " + numAffected);
    if(!err) {
      res.send(200);
      //res.redirect('/forum');
    }
  }

  Post.update(posty, { id: posty._id.toString() }, callback);
};
```

This is the console output for the above code:

```
53c54a0d4960ddc11495d7d7 this is posty
null 0
```

So as you can see, it isn't affecting any of the MongoDB documents, but it also isn't producing errors.

This is what happens on the client (Angular) side when a post is updated:

```
$scope.saveedit = function() {
      console.log($scope.post._id + " post id");
      // Now call update passing in the ID first then the object you are updating
      Post.update({ id:$scope.post._id }, $scope.post, function() {$location.path('/forum')});
};
```

After the redirect, `$location.path('/forum')`, none of the data is displayed as being updated...when I look in the database...nothing has changed either...it is like I am missing the step to `save` the changes...but I thought that `update` (a `PUT` request) would do that for me.

I use `ng-init="loadposts()"` when the `/forum` route is loaded:

```
$scope.loadposts = function() {
      $http.get('/api/posts').success(function (data) {$scope.posts = data});
};
```

Shouldn't all the new data be loaded after this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get you question right. You're asking how to prevent the redirection when nothing updated or why your data isnt updating in the database?

Comment: @BenDiamant why my data isnt updating in the database...that is the problem...otherwise I think it would load the changed data after the redirect because of my `ng-init` function.

Comment: @BenDiamant that log output is telling me that a.) it isn't changing the post for some reason, and b.) there are no errors

Comment: "toString()" on your post id in the mongoose update? I think thats your problem

Comment: @BenDiamant - tried it - no changes...still not finding what it needs

Comment: @BenDiamant - ive tried using `$scope.$apply()` in certain places...but I know that is only for when you need to update the scope after something outside of angular has happened...but i dont really think that is happening here...and it also just gives me an error saying that it is already happening and can't be run twice at the same time.

Comment: @BenDiamant `$scope.$apply()` is also probably irrelevant because it isn't finding what it needs in mongo apparently to even make the update.

Comment: @BenDiamant - this is what the put request looks like in the browser `__v
 0
 
_id
 "53c54a0d4960ddc11495d7d7"
 
content
 "lolasdfads"
 
date
 "Tue Jul 15 2014 11:34:37 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
 
posttitle
 "lol"
 
username
 "eamon.white7@gmail.com"
Source
{"_id":"53c54a0d4960ddc11495d7d7","posttitle":"lol","content":"lolasdfads","username":"eamon.white7@gmail.com","date":"Tue Jul 15 2014 11:34:37 GMT-0400 (EDT)","__v":0}`. When I look at the `_id` field in mongo console - it outputs `ObjectId(xxxxxx)` instead of just a number...am i mishandling something with regards to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server side output indicate that the update query doesn't match any document in the database.

I'm guessing that you are using Mongoose in NodeJS server side code to connect to mongodb.

If that the case, your update statement seems incorrect.

1. Instead of `{ id: .. }` it should be `{ _id: .. }`
2. Also the conditions object and updated object are swapped.

The statement should be like this:

```
Post.update({ _id: posty._id.toString() }, posty, callback);
```

If you are not using Mongoose, please eloborate more on which library you are using or better than that, show the code where the `Post` variable is defined in your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it.

the problem is that you are not using the Angular resource api correct.

**This code need to be changed:**

```
$scope.saveedit = function() {
   console.log($scope.post._id + " post id");
   Post.update({ id:$scope.post._id }, $scope.post, function()     {$location.path('/forum')});
};
```

Into:

```
    // Update existing Post
    $scope.saveedit = function() {
        var editedpost = new Post($scope.post); //New post object

        editedpost.$update(function() {
            $location.path('/forum');
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```

And as for the server code (taken from my own working module):

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
    var post == req.post;

    post = _.extend(post, req.body);

    post.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(400, {
            message: getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(post);
    }
});
```

};

Comment: ok - i changed the first chunk and i get `Error: editedpost.$update is not a function` - about to change the second chunk u provided

Comment: i changed to this: `exports.editsave = function(req, res, next) {
  //console.log(req.body.posttitle.toString() + " this is req.body");
  var post = req.body;

  post = _.extend(post, req.body);

  post.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, {
            message: getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(post);
    }
  });
};` but compiler wont get past the `$update` error

Comment: @ewizard Try use the updated angular code in my answer. the $update function is derived from the Post resource service you've created. If you can't use the $scope.post as a Post object, create a new one and use this API

Comment: i think i read somewhere that `$update` has to be used with a `$resource` object...so I tried this: `$scope.saveedit = function() {
        var editedpost = Post.get({ id:$scope.post._id }); //Your post object after it was changed

        editedpost.$update(function() {
            $location.path('/forum');
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };` and i get `PUT http://localhost:9000/api/posts
 
404 Not Found`

Comment: @ewizard don't use get. Just create a new one from the exisiting raw one

Comment: ok i think we are getting somewhere - i made the changes..and now i am getting an error because it is trying to put to `/api/posts` when it should be trying to put to `/api/posts/:id`...also...i removed `var post == req.body;` dont know what that was for - but it was throwing errors...also changed line to ` var post = _.extend(post, req.body);` dont know what that line does either lol

Comment: that whole function looks like this `exports.editsave = function(req, res, next) {
  //console.log(req.body.posttitle.toString() + " this is req.body");

  var post = _.extend(post, req.body);

  post.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, {
            message: getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(post);
    }
  });
};`

Comment: heh well it's for internal use. you right.

So what is the result at the moment?